# storing values from mysql table into an array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I googled around and found no valid solutions. Hope someone here will help.
This is my code:

```
            <?php 
        include "../includes/connection.php";
        $sql_select="SELECT title FROM questions";

        if (!$result=mysql_query($sql_select))
        {
        echo "Error<br>" . mysql_error($sql_select);
        die();
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
            echo "No questions!";
        } 
        else {

            $titles = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            print_r($titles);
        }
        ?>
```

For the purpose of my web application I need to put question titles into a new array.
I thought mysql_fetch_array() function creates an array by itself, but I guess I was wrong.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What are you getting when you do the print_r?

Comment: @Farid: He probably gets one result.

Comment: FYI don't pass the `$sql_select` string to mysql_error. Check the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from table');

$table = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    $row = array();
    foreach($r as $k=>$v) {
         $row[$k] = $v;
    }
    array_push($table,$row);
    unset($row);
}
```

$table will be a 3d array representation of your table. $table[0]['title'] will be the title of it's first row.

Answer (score 5):

You need to move `$titles = mysql_fetch_array($result);` into a loop like this:

```
$titles = array();
while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $titles[] = $title;
}
```

Another note, remove the argument you've placed in `mysql_error()`.

Comment: I can't accept it sooner than I'm allowed to. I will, don't worry :)

Comment: I would still declare `$titles` as `$titles = array()`. Makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: @Felix: Good point, it also makes sure there aren't any problems with other variables of that name defined previously.