# array in loop php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to fetch the data from table and store it in the array named "items" and then access it using index. I am getting an error "Undefined offset: 0" .  What is wrong in the code ?

```
$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))
{
    $name = $row['name'];

    $items = array();

    $items[$i] = $name;

    $i= $i +1;
}

echo $items[0];
echo $items[1];
```

Comment: define the i value `$i=0;`

Comment: check this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455548/storing-values-from-mysql-table-into-an-array-in-php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're recreating array on every iteration. Initialization of result array (`$items` in your code) should be outside of loop. E.g.:

```
$items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    $name = $row['name'];

    $items[] = $name;
}
echo $items[0];

echo $items[1];
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 5):

Define `$items` outside of your loop, define `$i = 0` outside your loop and change to `mysql_fetch_assoc` and try that.

```
$i = 0;
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
    $name = $row['name'];

    $items[$i] = $name;
    $i++;
}
echo $items[0];
echo $items[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are re-declaring your array each time inside loop which is incorrect.

```
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery))
{
  $items[] = $name = $row['name'];
}
echo $items[0];
echo $items[1];
```

Note: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `$i = 0;` before while loop
2. Add `$items = array();` before while loop, Remove it from inside while loop

   ```
    $i         = 0;
    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))

{

$name = $row['name'];

$items = array();

$items[] = $name;




}
if(isset($items[0])){

echo $items[0];
}

if(isset($items[1])){
echo $items[1];
}
```

No need of using $i

Answer (score 0):

Move `$items = array()` out of the while loop. It's been redefined multiple times and the `$item[0]` is lost. You only get the last item in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare your variables inside the loop and if you're just adding to a single dimensional array you can leave the $i off.

```
$items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery))
{
    $items[] = $row['name'];
}

print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and clean version:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))

{
   $items[] = $row['name'];

}


echo $items[0];
echo $items[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your array each time in the loop.

Do like that:

```
<?php
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $items[] = $name;
}
echo $items[0];
echo $items[1];
?>
```